# Barcode from string

Tags: php, class, barcode

I got an array with strings that are generated to a pdf in measurements to fit an A4 label sheet.

Now I would like to add barcodes below from each string value. Is there a class that can generate an img or similar to be compiled to html in the process.

From what I understand this: http://barcode-coder.com/fr/barcode-classe-php-pour-creer-des-code-barres-203.html does not allow multiple barcodes being generated into html for later printing.

Comment: TCPDF: [PHP code](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_027.phps), [example PDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_027.pdf)

Comment: @JaredFarrish That should be an Answer, not just a Comment, surely? Brief, but to the point. :)